# create installation file (.msi) for windows file system driver

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, minifilter

I have recently started working on windows file system minifilter driver. I want to create installer for my driver preferably .msi. I am using VS community edition to develop project.

I tried using Driver Install Package project in VS but that returned me nothing after build. MSDN states it's used to deploy the driver. So I guess we can't use to create installer.
Am I right?

In my quest I found out that there are APIs to develop custom installer called setupapis & DIFx. Tried developing installer with them but got errors (will make another question out of it). If this is the way are there any guides or examples available? MSDN has API specs only or atleast that's what I could find for those API but no guide on how to create installer from scratch.

Shall I need to use those APIs only or there's some available utility in VS which I can use to build installer?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a third party tool that can save you lots of time. [Advanced Installer can install drivers](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-driver.html), and other MSI authoring tools too.

You can use e free trial of Advanced Installer to test it, in about than 10 minutes you should have a working installer, the GUI is quite easy to work it (*we worked a lot to make it that easy to use*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we can't use third party tool as the software will be commercial. I guess I have to remove that part from question. Would like to hear more about the APIs though.